# Undefined value HTML::TokeParser

Tags: perl, html-parser

I'm trying to find tags in a html with a perl script.

```
 use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
 use Crypt::SSLeay;
 use HTML::TokeParser;
 $ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME}=0;

 my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new;
 $mech->get_local('salida2.html');
 my @links = $mech->links();
 print @links;


 my $parser = HTML::TokeParser->new('salida2.html') || die $!;
 my $tag = $parser->get_tag('ul');
```

I get this error **Can't call method "get_tag" on an undefined value at C:\Users\me\Documents\Scripts\parsing.pl line 9.**

salida2.html is under the same directory than the script and I'm also using it with an WWW::Mechanize::Firefox instance and it's working fine.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: and check if new returns an object... e.g. using `... or die $!`

Comment: @pavel It says No such file or directory at C:\Users\me\Documents\Scripts\parsing.pl. But it's there, under the same directory

Comment: Okay...and what is the content of the HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue is in the error you get. The file may be in the same directory as your script, but that doesn't mean that that's your working directory! Either `chdir` to the right directory or use a fully qualified path...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried it before but it seems I did a pasting mistake or something because now it's working!